# Can Xmonad treat left and right alt differently?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, xmonad

I have an application that utilizes <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to perform a function. When using this application in Xmonad, the combination <kbd>Mod1</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> triggers the function "swap the current window with the master window". By default, <kbd>ALT_L</kbd> and <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> are mapped to <kbd>Mod1</kbd>.

In my `.xinitrc`, before I start Xmonad, I've altered my key map with `xmodmap` such that <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> is not part of the <kbd>Mod1</kbd> definition. Despite this, Xmonad still performs the window swapping behavior when entering <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Xmonad seems to be unaware that <kbd>Mod1</kbd> no longer includes <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>.

Here is my `.xinitrc`

```
# Java's GUI can't handle some non-reparenting window managers like
# Xmonad without being told how to behave
export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1

# The right Alt key is useful in IntelliJ, tell Xmonad to ignore it
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap

# Start Xmonad
xmonad
```

Here is the output of `xmodmap` after Xmonad starts.

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I've recorded the sequence with `xev` and confirmed that the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> is never registered. Instead, several `FocusIn`/`FocusOut` events occur after the <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> is recorded.

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 1432589, (92,374), root:(93,375),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

PropertyNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    atom 0x155 (WM_STATE), time 1433760, state PropertyNewValue

FocusOut event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyPointer

FocusIn event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   16  0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1200001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 1434117, (92,374), root:(93,375),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Another interesting observation is that `xev` reports the `state` of each key event as 8, regardless of whether <kbd>ALT_L</kbd> or <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> is being pressed. The constant `Mod1Mask` in `/usr/include/X11/X.h` is defined as 8. The following sequence is <kbd>ALT_L</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> followed by <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>.

```
KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4126632, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4126850, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x8, keycode 41 (keysym 0x66, f), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4126930, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x8, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4126969, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x0, keycode 41 (keysym 0x66, f), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4127907, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x0, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4128123, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x8, keycode 41 (keysym 0x66, f), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4128164, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x8, keycode 108 (keysym 0xffea, Alt_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 32, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0xc0, subw 0x0, time 4128203, (85,488), root:(86,489),
    state 0x0, keycode 41 (keysym 0x66, f), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (66) "f"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

So the question now becomes, if `xmodmask` says that <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> is not <kbd>mod1</kbd>, why is `X` reporting <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> as if it was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `Xmonad` is treating <kbd>ALT_R</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> as if it was <kbd>mod1</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> is because `X` is setting the `mod1Mask` bit in the `state` field of the `KeyEvent`, as shown in the `xev` output in the question. `Xmonad` is unaware that <kbd>ALT_R</kbd> is the key being pressed because `X` tells it that <kbd>ENTER</kbd> was pressed with `state = mod1Mask`.

Why `X` is not respecting `xmodmap` is a separate question, asked here:
[Why isn't X treating ALT_L and ALT_R differently w/r/t Mod1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239988/why-isnt-x-treating-alt-l-and-alt-r-differently-w-r-t-mod1)

Answer (score 3):

Xmonad can only do this if you use different modifier-masks.  In its source code it mentions a special case for example:

```
-- modMask lets you specify which modkey you want to use. The default
-- is mod1Mask ("left alt").  You may also consider using mod3Mask
-- ("right alt"), which does not conflict with emacs keybindings. The
-- "windows key" is usually mod4Mask.
--
myModMask       = mod1Mask
```

The suggestion uses *two* modifier masks because none of the predefined key-modifiers in X include the **`alt`** (or **`meta`**) key.  Those include *Shift*, *Lock*, *Control* — and 5 unspecified modifier keys.  Xmonad has no special knowledge of any of these keys other than (reading the source code) Shift and Lock.

So you must assign **`Alt_L`** and **`Alt_R`** to separate modifier masks if you want them to be used for different purposes in Xmonad.

Comment: You mention that I must assign `ALT_R` to a separate modifier mask if I want to use it for a different purpose. My question is how can I use it for NO purpose. I don't want Xmonad to interpret it at all.

Comment: I've digged into the Xmonad source and the Haskell X11 package source. The Haskell X11 package defines `xK_ALT_L` and `xK_ALT_R`, but it doesn't tie their definitions to `mod1Mask` in any way. Xmonad doesn't import the definition of the Alt keys, so it is not special casing anything either. They should just see whatever flags the X server tells them. I see no reason why Xmonad would interpret `ALT_R` as `Mod1` given the output of `xmodmap` in the question overview, yet for some reason it does.